# POSIX Regex to capture up to x number of occurrences

Tags: regex, posix

I am using POSIX regex and trying to capture all occurrences of a given pattern in the string.

The string is

```
N2800 W08700-N2730 W08430-N2645 W08415-N2500 W08630-N2430>>W08900-N2630 W08845-N2800 W08700. TOP FL360. MOV NE 5KT. WKN.
```

I tried the following but it only matches the first occurrence (N2800 W08700):

```
([NS]\d{4}(\s|>>)[EW]\d{5}){1,11}
```

Doesn't the `{1,11}` at the end say to match the pattern between 1 and 11 times ?

Comment: How do you know it would only match the first? What is your command, Would you present a Minimal Working Example please?

Comment: The problem is that there's a `space` character between matches. Your regex will only catch one match because it doesn't match the space between.

Comment: @PoulBak actually it's a `-`

Comment: @Nick: You're right, but the argument is the same

Comment: @PoulBak absolutely!

Comment: Your regex matches one time only because of the trailing `-` or `.` after the `[EW]` portion. You can fix it by adding a character class after that portion to capture the `-` or `.`. Try [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/Gcjvy6/1)

Comment: Your pattern is fine, see [here](https://regex101.com/r/z9nabM/1). It's just not matching globally. Please let us know which kind of program or tool you're using so we can tell you how to enable that option.

Comment: I was running through the regex tester at https://regex101.com/r/dX8cN8/1

Comment: can you please give a sample of input text and expected output text.

Answer (score -1):

I think that `\d` is not POSIX.

`{1,11}` means one to eleven *consecutive* matches, but you have `-` after the first one. Try perhaps
`([NS]\d{4}(\s|>>)[EW]\d{5}-?){1,11}`

```
$ echo  'N2800 W08700-N2730 W08430-N2645 W08415-N2500 W08630-N2430>>W08900-N2630 W08845-N2800 W08700. TOP FL360. MOV NE 5KT. WKN' \
 | grep -P '([NS]\d{4}(\s|>>)[EW]\d{5}-?){1,11}'
>>>>>>>>>N2800 W08700-N2730 W08430-N2645 W08415-N2500 W08630-N2430>>W08900-N2630 W08845-N2800 W08700<<<<<<<<<. TOP FL360. MOV NE 5KT. WKN
```

Note that `-P` choses Perl regexp.

```
$ echo  'N2800 W08700-N2730 W08430-N2645 W08415-N2500 W08630-N2430>>W08900-N2630 W08845-N2800 W08700. TOP FL360. MOV NE 5KT. WKN' \
| perl -pe 's/([NS]\d{4}(\s|>>)[EW]\d{5}-?){1,11}/MATCH/'
MATCH. TOP FL360. MOV NE 5KT. WKN
```